# Performance ramifications of filtering onNeo4j relationships

Tags: neo4j

I am considering filtering by a parameter on a relationship.
For example:

If I have a graph containing

```
Create (n:Car)-[r:DRIVES_ON {side: 'left'}]->(m:Country {Name: 'England'}) return n,m;
```

I want to extract using

```
Match (n:Car)-[r:DRIVES_ON]-(m:Country) where r.side ='left' return r;
```

Is this a BAD idea because of performance reasons?

Answer (score 4):

Since there are only two options I would just have two separate relationships:

```
(Car)-[:DRIVES_ON_LEFT]->(Country)
(Car)-[:DRIVES_ON_RIGHT]->(Country)
```

But it would be nice to know more about your domain.

Comment: This is a contrived example. What I want to find out is -What are the performance penalties (because of the way data is stored on disk/memory) of filtering on relationships

Answer (score 4):

Nicole is right,

the property data is **currently** stored separately from the relationships on disk while the type is stored in the relationship-record. So checking for just the type is much faster as no property has to be loaded (lazy loading).

So loading properties in a high performance traversal case can hurt (on cold caches) and uses more memory to fill the caches with. Esp. as *all* properties are loaded in one go, at least the ones that fit into the property records. Only larger arrays and larger strings are not loaded by default but lazily on access.

Comment: What sort on performance dip should I expect? Is all the data for a relationship type stored sequentially on disk? If this is the case 'would the disk get all the data it requires in a single extraction?' Obviously this would drastically change the performance on the query